# Unity ScreenToWorldPoint behaving differently on Mac (compared to PC)?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, screen, coordinates

I have written some tools to be used in Unity for level editing in my project. But when opening the project on a Mac, there is one thing that seems to behave differently. Getting the coordinates within the scene seem to work in the same fashion, but when I call

camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(posInScene)

on Windows the correct position is returned but on the mac it returns something entirely different. Any ideas, what could be the reason for this? Or how I could fix this? The code is run in OnSceneGUI. Of course if things need to be written differently for a mac, then I'll just make the code compile platform dependently. Understanding the the reason for the difference would of course also be nice.

A possibly related thing I've noticed is that camera.rect is always camera.rect(x:0.00, y:0.00, width:1.00, height:1.00) on PC, but for some weird reason on a mac for "Layout" events it's (x:0.00, y:-0.99, width:2.00, height:2.00). Could someone explain that? :o

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the root cause of this issue, but the workaround is to use `HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay` instead of `camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`.